# -Xlint recompilation. Why is not turn on by default?

Tags: java

I wonder if compiling with -Xlint has some negative effects on building process or project ?

If no, why this is not turn on by default in java compiler?

Can I just turn on all warnigs, and forget about this even during building release version of my appliaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn on all warnings if you like.  There are much better tools for doing static analysis which also help you fix the issues and IMHO Xlint is there for historical reasons.